# Subtracting columns in postgresql table

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I have a table with four columns ID, Break name, Time Started, Time Finished.

The data set for Time started and Time finished is Time without Time zone.

I want to add another Column called Duration and want it tp subtract the Time finished with time started. So that on each line that data has been inputted on the duration column will display how long the break was.

Comment: In relational database you usually do not store data that can easily be calculated by existing data. So there is no need to "add a column" that contains that information. Simply calculate it "on-the-fly" when you select from the table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Mureinik has pointed out, you can do math on timestamps in a query. To fix your table you need to add a duration (or whatever name you prefer) column to your table and the populate the column with an UPDATE query.

First I would create a sandbox table to test out these changes. And when you're happy with the results, you can modify the actual table.

Copy everything from `mytable` to `test`

```
CREATE TABLE test
AS
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
```

Add the new column with data type interval

```
ALTER TABLE test
ADD COLUMN duration interval
```

Populate the new column

```
UPDATE test
SET duration = time_finished - time_started
```

Once you're happy with the results in the `test` table, run the same commands on your live table.

Answer (score 11):

Subtracting two timestamps will return an `interval` that's the difference between them, which should fit your bill:

```
SELECT *, time_finished - time_Started AS duration
FROM   mytable
```

Comment: Thank You for that. Where would i put this command ? is it when a create the column in the table?

Comment: @DavidBJones I was trying to illustrate (and probably didn't do a good enough job) that you don't need to add a column - you can always calculate the duration on the fly, when you query the table.